# Showing the relation "$(x\sim y) \iff x-y $ is even" to be symmetric

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Definition of an equivalence relation:

It has to be: 
Reflexive:  $(x \sim x) \forall x$
Symmetric: $(x\sim y)\iff (y \sim x)$ 
Transitive: $(x \sim y) \land (y \sim z) \Rightarrow(x \sim z)$

---

Prove the equivalence relation on the set $\mathbb{Z}$:

$x\sim y :\iff x-y$ is an even number

Proof of symmetry:

There exists a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x-y =2k$ which is the relation $x\sim y$.

The changed relation $y\sim x$ of our given equation gives us $[y-x=(-2)k]$ $\lor$ [$y-x=2(-k)]$

Thus it is symmetric. Proved.

---

My idea was: If $x-y=2k$ then $2k$ is positive because of $x>y$.
And when we change the equation to: $y-x$ then I have to the choice between saying: $(-2)k$ or $2*(-k)$

Am I also allowed to define my variables like that? $x=2$ and $-y=k$ 
So I would get $-x=-2$ and $y=k$

Comment: "*Am I also allowed to define my variables like that(???)*"  You may inspect specific cases by using specific values for $x,y$ and others... however inspecting such cases generally only yield information about *those cases specifically* and do not work for proving generalities about *all* cases.

Comment: Whether or not $x$ is greater than $y$ or $x$ is less than $y$ is irrelevant.  It does not matter whether or not $x-y$ is positive or negative or even zero.  All that matters is that $x-y$ is even.  While true that $x-y=2k$ the right hand side does not have a minus sign while $y-x=-2k$ does have a minus sign that does not imply that $2k$ is positive and $-2k$ is negative.  It could have been the case that $k$ was a negative number in which case $2k$ was the negative one and $-2k$ was the positive one.

Comment: Thank you for that insight!! I never have seen it this way

Comment: Finally... do not apply too much significance to the letter used for evenness... If $x-y$ is even then all we care about is that it is $2$ times "*something*."  That "something" might be completely different than any other number mentioned so far.  So, for instance, if $x-y$ was even and $y-z$ was even, we know that $x-y$ is $2$ times *something* and that $y-z$ is $2$ times *another something*... possibly the same something but possibly different.  To keep them separate in our minds we use different letters for these and write it as $x-y=2k$ and $y-z=2\ell$.

Comment: If you are inspecting the case of if $x=2$ and $y=k$... and you are told that $x-y$ is even... i.e. that $2-k$ is even... then you know that that is $2$ times *something* and that *something* might be different than all other previously seen numbers/letters/names... so we would need to use a different letter than $k$ since that is already in use.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to verify is $x-x=2\times0$, $x-y=2k\implies y-x=2(-k)$ and $x-y=2k,\,y-z=2l\implies x-z=2(k+l)$.